# Urllib read inside except does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, try-except

Im trying to read the source code (html) from multiple websites and use the following code. As long as the site is encoded in utf-8 it works just fine but a site encoded in ISO-8859-1 causes some problems. As you can see in the code below it is supposed to go to the second except block and when running the program the debug print inside the block is printed. However, the variable *html_doc* does not get any value. It does not seem to be anything wrong with the *f.read().decode...* statement as the now commented out line with the same statement outside the try-except block works perfectly. Why does this happen? I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to solve the problem as I thus far has been unable to figure it out on my own.

```
def getSource(self, target_url):
    print(target_url)
    html_doc = None
    try:
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(target_url)
    except:
        return None
    #html_doc = f.read().decode("ISO-8859-1")
    try:
        html_doc = f.read().decode("utf-8")     # Save source code of URL to html_doc
        print(html_doc)
    except:
        print("I Went here")
        html_doc = f.read().decode("ISO-8859-1")   # Use other encoding if failed
        print("I SAID SO")
    print(html_doc)
    return html_doc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest reading the file into a variable first, then decoding it after you have closed the file. I believe what is happening here is that you open the file, read the data, it fails, then you read some more data, but there is no more data left to read so html_doc ends up being empty.

so something like this:

```
html_doc = f.read()
try:
    html_doc = html_doc.decode("utf-8")
except:
    html_doc = html_doc.decode("ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: I just assumed that calling f.read() again would read the whole site again, but apperently I was wrong. This solved the problem just fine so thank you very much!